# how to trigger an action when gesture was initiated from a different object\class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

my code UIViewController is instantiating an object\class, which is a UIView that has a frame which I draw a filled circle etc. I added a gesture to that second class frame that when a tap occur i want to close\release that second class and trigger some method written in the first object (in the UIViewController).
Now this second class recognize the tap ,but i'm not sure how to dealloc the class from within itself and tell the first class to do something (call a method)?

Hope this is clear, any idea how to go about that?

Thanks

Comment: I would set up a delegate or IBOutlet to the first class. When you handle the gesture in the second class, send a message to its delegate (the first class) that deallocates the second class and does what you need within the first class (which is now the first responder)

Comment: @slev the IBOutlet to be in the first class? How do i send a message to that IBOutlet or delegate. If you can elaborate with some code if possible that would be great.

Comment: Absolutely. Let me get a little sample code together and I'll add it as an answer (much easier to format it there)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to create a delegate for the second class. For example, we'll just assume there is FirstClass and SecondClass, each their own file.

In FirstClass, when you set up its instance of SecondClass (instantiating the UIView), you would have something like the following:

```
SecondClass *class2 = [[SecondClass alloc] init....];
// set up the delegate, which basically creates a link between SecondClass and FirstClass;
class2.delegate = self;
```

In SecondClass.h, you would need to set up something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;
```

and in SecondClass.m, you would have a synthesized value for the delegate as well as your gesture handling method:

```
// add the FirstClass header file;
#import "FirstClass.h"

// synthesize the value;
@synthesize delegate;

// later on into the implementation file;
- (void)gestureHandlingMethod:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    // do whatever you need for the gesture in SecondClass;
    // send a message to FirstClass (now defined as delegate of SecondClass);
    [self.delegate handleGesture:gesture forClass:self];
}
```

Finally, you need to add this gesture handling method to FirstClass so that it does what you need. So, in FirstClass.h, add `-(void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture forClass:(id)secondClass;`. Then finish up by adding this method to FirstClass.m, like the following:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture forClass:(id)secondClass {
    // do what you want here from within the FirstClass;
    [self doSomethingWithGestureIfYouWant:gesture];
    // then deallocate SecondClass if that's what you want to do;
    [secondClass dealloc]; // you may need to specify [(SecondClass *)secondClass dealloc];
}
```

That should do it. It's just a nice little way of linking different files together. Hopefully this helps you out.